# Before redirecting from one page to other using anchor tag can we call a function in javascript then redirect to that particular page in react

Tags: html, redirect

page1 
 page2

Javascript

function call redirect() {...}

in page 1 right now,
when click pg2

can we call a function and the redirect to pg2.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the title, you want to invoke a function just before going to another page.

The following example explains how you can achieve this.

Somewhere in your JSX:

```js
<a onClick = { myFunction }>Go to page 2</a>
```

Somewhere else, probably outside of `render` or `return`.

```js
function myFunction {
  // do things
  // redirect to page 2
  location.assign(`/page2/`);
}
```